# Unable to get attributes when using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am unable to get attributes. Just a simple XML:

```
<comments>
<id auto="5" hallo="1234567">ID</id>
<comment hybrid="1">Comment</comment>
<type>
<name surname="0">Type</name>
<label>
<case_0>In</case_0>
<case_1>Out</case_1>
</label>
</type>
</comments>
```

And the PHP code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filepath);
foreach ($xml->children() as $children)
{
$attributes = $children->attributes();
print_r($attributes->hallo);
}
```

The output should be *1234567*... however the printed output is *NULL*. Am I missing something here because methods *getName()* and *getValue()* works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the above code is correct. and it is working fine for me.This will be the output

SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 1234567 ).

There might be some issue in loading file . Check your file path for correct result.